# Do "Tab Groups" count as a selection for the purposes of "Don't load tabs until selected"?

Tags: firefox

I have "Don't load tabs until selected" active in my preferences, and I use Tab Groups to manage my tabs.

After I close and reopen Firefox, if I open the tab groups viewer, I notice that Firefox refreshes the screenshots of the various tabs I have open.

**Does this count as "selecting" the tabs?  That is, does viewing the tab groups interface load all tabs into memory?**

Answer (score 1):

Viewing the "Tab groups" doesn't count as selecting the tabs. Only manually selecting the tabs does.

The screenshots of the tabs you see being refreshed when you are viewing the Tab groups is actually Firefox loading the screenshots from its memory. If you are unsure, try clicking on the tab and see the website load only after you manually select the tab.